# Newton Raphson for logistic regression

Tags: r, algorithm, logistic-regression

I did code for Newton Raphson for logistic regression. Unfortunately  I tried many data there is no convergence. there is a mistake I do not know where is it. Can anyone help to figure out what is the problem.

First the data is as following; y indicate the response (0,1) , Z is 115*30  matrix which is the exploratory variables. I need to estimate the 30 parameters.

```
y = c(rep(0,60),rep(1,55))
X = sample(c(0,1),size=3450,replace=T)
Z = t(matrix(X,ncol=115))
#The code is ;
B     = matrix(rep(0,30*10),ncol=10)
B[,1] = matrix(rep(0,30),ncol=1)
for(i in 2 : 10){
  print(i)
  p       <- exp(Z %*%as.matrix(B[,i])) / (1 + exp(Z %*% as.matrix(B[,i])))
  v.2     <- diag(as.vector(1 * p*(1-p)))
  score.2 <- t(Z) %*% (y - p) # score function
  increm  <- solve(t(Z) %*% v.2 %*% Z) 
  B[,i]   =  as.matrix(B[,i-1])+increm%*%score.2
  if(B[,i]-B[i-1]==matrix(rep(0.0001,30),ncol=1)){
    return(B)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it!  You're updating `p` based on `B[,i]`, you should be using `B[,i-1]` ...

While I was finding the answer, I cleaned up your code and incorporated the results in a function. R's built-in `glm` seems to work (see below).  One note is that this approach is likely to be unstable: fitting a binary model with 30 predictors and only 115 binary responses, and without any penalization or shrinkage, is extremely optimistic ...

```
set.seed(101)
n.obs <- 115
n.zero <- 60
n.pred <- 30
y <- c(rep(0,n.zero),rep(1,n.obs-n.zero))
X <- sample(c(0,1),size=n.pred*n.obs,replace=TRUE)
Z <- t(matrix(X,ncol=n.obs))
```

R's built-in `glm` fitter does work (it uses iteratively reweighted least squares, not N-R):

```
g1 <- glm(y~.-1,data.frame(y,Z),family="binomial")
```

(If you want to view the results, `library("arm"); coefplot(g1)`.)

```
## B_{m+1} = B_m + (X^T V_m X)^{-1} X^T (Y-P_m)
```

NRfit function:

```
NRfit <- function(y,X,start,n.iter=100,tol=1e-4,verbose=TRUE) {
    ## used X rather than Z just because it's more standard notation
    n.pred <- ncol(X)
    B <-  matrix(NA,ncol=n.iter,
                 nrow=n.pred)
    B[,1] <- start
    for (i in 2:n.iter) {
        if (verbose) cat(i,"\n")
        p <- plogis(X %*% B[,i-1])
        v.2 <- diag(c(p*(1-p)))
        score.2 <- t(X) %*% (y - p) # score function
        increm <- solve(t(X) %*% v.2 %*% X) 
        B[,i] <- B[,i-1]+increm%*%score.2
        if (all(abs(B[,i]-B[,i-1]) < tol)) return(B)
    }
    B
}

matplot(res1 <- t(NRfit(y,Z,start=coef(g1))))
matplot(res2 <- t(NRfit(y,Z,start=rep(0,ncol(Z)))))
all.equal(res2[6,],unname(coef(g1))) ## TRUE
```